# Spring Boot. Why ConfigurationProperties prefix ignored if @Value used

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

I have:

```yaml
inner:
  system:
    number: "01"
    id: "ID"
```

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "inner.system")
@Slf4j(topic = "Configuration Properties Logger")
@Data
public class ConfigurationProperties {
  private String number;
  @Value("${inner.system.id})
  private String id;
}
```

and everything loaded correctly.

But if I change `@Value("${inner.system.id})` to `@Value("${id})` (because of specified prefix `"inner.system"`) it fails.
I really confused with this.

### Question

Is this the correct behavior or is there something incorrectly configured in my project?

Comment: Because these types of reading configuration  work independently if I am not mistaken(I am not). And in this case you have to use one of approach not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a small mistake in the configuration. It should be,

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "inner.system")
....
```

The `@Value` annotation requires the full property path, including the prefix. In this scenario, the full property path is `inner.system.id`
In your case, the correct annotation would be @Value("${inner.system.id}") because the full path is "inner.system.id."